# Rails 4, creating model entries by parsing xml file. Need current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Fairly new with rails and am digging with a new web app. I'm parsing an XML file uploaded by the user. The parsing is done with a before_save call in the `upload.rb` model file.

In the xml parsing function (`parse_xml`), my intention is to create a new model for the XML children elements and save all the attributes.

The problem I am facing is this:

As I understand, current_user is a controller helper function from devise and is not available in the models. The current model I have (Items Model containing the XML child elements) is tagged against a user_id (The current_user). The Items model does not have controllers at the moment and there is no way I can think of passing in the current_user's ID attribute into the Uploads model.

Again, to my understanding, the Uploads model works on the `parse_xml` function before actually running the `@upload.save` function in the uploads_controller.rb.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. While I know `Thread.current[:user]` is suggested by a lot of people, as a learner, i prefer getting the right approach in my head rather than have a #facepalm moment when someone looks at my code :-)

Update:
Since Items records require an upload_id value, the records cannot be created until the Parent Upload record is created. Is this the reason why I also get an `uninitialized constant Upload::Item` error during the before_save execution in `Upload#create` route?

I'm not sure where things are going wrong!